# pytest fixture to introspect calling function

Tags: python, introspection, fixtures, pytest

I have a test class and a setup function that looks like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope='function')
def setup(self, request):
    self.client = MyClass()
    first_patcher = patch('myclass.myclass.function_to_patch')
    first_mock = first_patcher.start()
    first_mock.return_value = 'foo'
    value_to_return = getattr(request, 'value_name', None)
    second_patcher = patch('myclass.myclass.function_two')
    second_mock = second_patcher.start()
    second_mock.return_value = value_to_return
    #could clean up my mocks here, but don't care right now
```

I see in the documentation for pytest, that introspection can be done for a module level value:
    val = getattr(request.module, 'val_name', None)

But, I want to be able to specify different values to return based on the test I am in. So I am looking for a way to introspect the test_function not the test_module.

http://pytest.org/latest/fixture.html#fixtures-can-introspect-the-requesting-test-context

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `request.function` to get to the test function.  Just follow the link on the b wepage you referenced to see what is available on the test `request` object :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the documentation has changed since the time of the accepted answer.
At least for me it was not clear how to

> Just follow the link

So I thought I'd update this thread with the link itself:

https://pytest.org/en/6.2.x/reference.html#request

**Edit December 2021**

Even when the link is correct now I think this statement from the pytest documentation is just not correct:

> Fixture functions can accept the request object to introspect the “requesting” test function ...

While I found some examples for getting attributes of the module I did not find a single working example of introspecting the test function that requests the fixture. May be related to collection and runtime order.

What really helped me to get the desired behavior was to use the factory idiom a little further down in the pytest documentation:

https://pytest.org/en/6.2.x/fixture.html#factories-as-fixtures

Set up the fixture factory

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def getQueryResult() -> object:
    def _impl(_mrId: int = 7622):
        return QueryResult(_mrId)

    return _impl
```

Usage

```
# Concrete value
def test_foo(getQueryResult):
    queryResult = getQueryResult(4711)
    ...

# Default value
def test_bar(getQueryResult):
    queryResult = getQueryResult()
    ...
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30555127)